# Why is AdMob iOS SDK 7.0 not support iOS 8

Tags: sdk, ios8, admob

I've updated from their AdMob iOS SDK 6.0 or something version to 7.0.0 like a month ago and everything for iOS 8 was working fine. Today out of nowhere every time I load my app in device in the debug area it states...

You are currently using version 7.0.0 of the SDK, which doesn't officially support iOS 8. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent sdk version, 7.1.0, to get iOS 8 support, including a fix for smart banner rendering in landscape mode.

Why all of a sudden is iOS SDK 7.0.0 not supported by iOS 8? So every time I have to update the AdMob SDK or the admob ad won't work for iOS8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this too. It still supports iOS8, they just haven't changed the message.  Admob SDK 6.12.0 still supports iOS8 too. What they are really saying is that there is a bug that they have fixed and you should upgrade to the latest version. I like this message, it always says if you are not using the latest version. If you are still in development you should always upgrade to the latest version of the SDK if you can. The difference between 7.0.0 and 7.1.0 is quite important, they were missing including one of the frameworks, so it is important that you use 7.1.0 instead of 7.0.0 - I think this was causing some ads not to play - https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/rel-notes#ios